# Delete Element within a List based on the Order

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I want to do the following, deleting the element of a list that do not match an increasing order as example:

{1,2,3,4,6,5,7,8}->{1,2,3,4,6,7,8}

I've thought of using DeleteCases but I'm not able to specify a criteria for the pattern withing the same list.
Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your question is under-specified. E.g., do you mean the result list must be strictly increasing, or the elements of it must be cases from the target that were such?

Comment: Hi, maybe I'm misunderstanding. The list I've is exactly like the one in the example I'm putting and I would like to keep all the element that do increase progressively except those one that go agains its previous element.
I'm trying to write it properly since I've to apply it to a list of lists

Comment: You might use `Differences` to detect decreasing elements, e.g. `Sign /@ Differences@{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8}` and then use that to delete elements from the list.

Comment: @Yyrkoon: As stated, there can be lists where a solution outputs the desired result for your *one* example, but not on others - the example is ambiguous. What should result be for say `{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 2, 4, 9, 6}`?  In any case, see if `Pick[#, UnitStep[Differences@Prepend[#, 0] - 1], 1] &@list` or `FixedPoint[
 Pick[#, UnitStep[Differences@Prepend[#, 0] - 1], 1] &, list]` floats your boat...

Comment: But Differences will work me only if I've one unit increasing  list, already if I've

{3,1,2,4,5,8,7,6}

It will not

Comment: What should be the result of {8,1,8,1}?

Comment: As the original question was stated, {3,1,2,4,5,8,7,6} should give {3,4,5,7}. If that's not what you meant, then additional information on your goal is required.

Comment: This kind of "here's what I want"..."yes, but I also need this"..."well, almost, but I need this too..." is counter-productive. Please update the question with sufficient use-case examples to cover your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use repeated replacement, this will only keep elements that are strictly increasing.

```
list = {1,2,3,4,6,5,7,8};
list = list//. {a___, x_, y_, b___} /; y < x :> {a, x, b}
```

Which gives:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8}
```

In the case that the all elements in `Rest@list` are less than the first element, a decreasing list for instance, it will return only the first element.

Comment: This will be *very* slow for large lists, though the OP has not specified size requirements.

Comment: It is instructive if OP is interested in learning patterns more than fast calculations so I thought I'd offer it as an alternative. But you're right it will be slow on large lists.

Comment: Agreed, and +1 for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! to all of you and to @ciao for all his comments I know that it has been hard for you all guys to get it through considering how confusing I'm sometimes

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 5, 4, 9, 12, 11};

Union@(Max /@ Table[Take[a, i], {i, Length[a]}])
```

(*
{1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12}
*)

Comment: `Union[FoldList[Max, list]]`... does same thing.

Comment: @ciao  Oooh... indeed.  Best answer.  +1

Comment: Not even sure it *is* an answer, until we get clarification :-) And +1 on your take.

Comment: Or `DeleteDuplicates[FoldList[Max, list]]`.